# Trouble testing redux activity in a mocked component -- dispatched action doesn't change state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I am testing a `Lineup` component that checks for user verification when submitting the lineup. Essentially, this:

```js
const Lineup = () => {
  const verified = useSelector(getIsUserVerifiedForContest);

  function onClickEnter() {
    if (!verified) {
      showVerificationModal();
      return;
    }
    submitLineup();
  }

  const onVerified = () => {
    hideVerificationModal();
    onClickEnter(); // at which point verified should be true
  };

  return (
    <>
      {showingVerificationModal && (
        <VerificationModal
          verificationComplete={onVerified}
          toggle={hideVerificationModal}
        />
      )}
      <button onClick={onClickEnter}>SUBMIT</button>
   </>
}
```

To test that it behaves correctly when an unverified user completes the verification using the modal, I'm trying to mock the modal and the verification. Mocking the modal is fine:

```js
jest.mock("../../../../../../browser/containers/VerificationModal", () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: ({ verificationComplete }) => (
      <div data-testid="MockVerificationModal">
        <button onClick={verificationComplete}>Mock-Verify</button>
      </div>
    ),
  }))
```

But I'm having trouble updating the verified state in the background. I've tried dispatching an action (simple, not async) to the store in between showing the modal and clicking its button. I've even debugged into the reducer, and I see that the action is being sent correctly, but when I break on the line after the dispatch and call `store.getState()`, it hasn't changed.

Here is my test code. I'll try to include as much as needed but no more :P

```js
let store;

const setupStore = ({ urlParams = "", storeOverrides = {} } = {}) => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory({
    initialEntries: [`myurl`],
  });

  store = configureStore({ ...initialState, ...storeOverrides });

  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Lineup />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

 describe("Not verified", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        setupStore(userOverride({ vStatus: 0 })); // set up the unverified user
        checkStartingState(); // runs sanity checks
        fireEvent.click(getEnterButton());
      });

      it("Shows the verification modal", async () => {
        await waitFor(() => expectTestId("MockVerificationModal"));
      });

      describe("Upon verification", () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          store.dispatch(postVerifyUserStatus(1));   // debug breakpoints mentioned above
          fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/mock-verify/i, { exact: false }));
        });

        it("Hides the verification modal", () => {
          expectText("mock-verify", false);
        });

        it("Submits (and shows success modal)", async () => {
          await expectSuccessModal();
        });
      });
    });
```

I really thought this manual dispatch was the answer to how to test the changing state in the background but as I said it's not working! I can't put the dispatch call in the mock because `jest.mock` is hoisted and can't use any imports or variables or anything.

I've considered mocking whatever endpoint the verification modal calls, but I really don't want this test to have to know anything about how the verification modal works.

So the main question is, why is this action not affecting the store?